# How to implement identity of mongodb correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Every time I call createasync in the below code, mongoclient cannot map the property correctly. It creates two fields: email and Email. If I change the BsonElement attribute to the exact property, `[BsonElement(nameof(Email))]`, it gives an error.

> BsonSerializationException: The property 'UserName' of type
> 'Company.Project.Domain.Documents.UserDocument' cannot use element name
> 'UserName' because it is already being used by property 'UserName' of
> type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`

I also asked ChatGPT to find a solution, but I didn't understand if there were any other issues because the implementation stores the access property differently.

```
public class UserDocument : IdentityUser<ObjectId>
{
    public override ObjectId Id { get; set;}
    
    [AllowNull][BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("email")]
    public override string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    
    // AI give solution
    /*
    [BsonIgnore]
    public new string Email
    {
        get { return base.UserName; }
        set { base.UserName = value; }
    }
    
    [AllowNull][BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("Email")]
    public string EmailField { get; set; } = null!;
    */
}
```

UserStore = Follow AI suggestion break UserStore implementation and i afraid it also break other stuff. ex, UserManager default implementation. i dont want to reinvent UserManager class.

```
public class UserStore<TUser> : 
    IUserStore<TUser>,
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<ObjectId>
{

    private readonly IMongoCollection<TUser> _users;

    public UserStore(IMongoDatabase database)
    {
        _users = database.GetCollection<TUser>("users");
    }
    public async Task<TUser?> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _users.Find(u => u.NormalizedUserName == normalizedUserName).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<string?> GetUserNameAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.UserName);
    }
}
```

Startup

```
services.AddIdentityCore<UserDocument>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<UserDocument>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IUserStore<>), typeof(UserStore<>));
services.AddTransient<UserManager<UserDocument>>();
```

IndexModel

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    IdentityUser document = new()
    {
        UserName = "test",
        NormalizedUserName = _userManager.NormalizeName("test"),
        Email = "asdlakakld@yahoo.com",
        NormalizedEmail = _userManager.NormalizeEmail("asdlakakld@yahoo.com"),
        
    };
    document.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(document, "test");
    await _userManager.CreateAsync(document);
    return Page();
}
```